# Catch all Salesforce Flow Error Emails with Apex Class

Tags: apex, trigger

Salesforce sends Emails once the Flow hits the Error to Apex Exception Email Recipient(s).
I need to create an ApexClass that would catch those Emails and save them in a custom Object in Salesforce with few information (User, Error Message, Link to failed flow or Apex, Flow or ApexClass Name). I am an Apex Beginner. Can you help me with advices regarding Apex Methods (which to use) and Triggers?
P.S. I do not want to use already created Package from Salesforce AppExchange.

Appologies if my question is too broad or too dummy.

Thank you in advance.

Kind regards,
GD

Answer (score 1):

You can also do

- Create a platform event with required fields
- Add fault path to the flow and insert/create PE Whenever a error
  occurs With flow
- write a trigger/flow on PE and insert the data into the custom object

Comment: Good suggestion and isolated to just Flows rather than any Apex exception. Will this catch Limits errors?

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement your apex class with the Apex class named **Messaging.InboundEmailHandler**

So the steps you need to follow for this implementation are: Create an email service in Salesforce then add your apex class to this email service. When you turn ON the email service, Salesforce generates an email that you need to add to your Gmail account. So when an email comes from the salesforce flow, it will sent directly to the apex class that you add to your email service. The apex class should implement the Messaging.InboundEmailHandler. Then you can retrieve the email body and save it in a custom field. You need to study this stuff before implementation.

*Please refer to this documentation*

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_email_inbound_using.htm

Comment: How would you do this in the context of a Flow error email?

Comment: So the steps you need to follow for this implementation are:
Create an email service in Salesforce then add your apex class to this email service.
When you turn ON the email service, Salesforce generates an email that you need to add to your Gmail account. So when an email comes from the salesforce flow, it will sent directly to the apex class that you add to your email service. The apex class should implement the Messaging.InboundEmailHandler. Then you can retrieve the email body and save it in a custom field. You need to study this stuff before implementation. Thanks

Comment: I would add that information to your answer to make it more complete.

Comment: I added that information to my answer. Thanks, Fred for your response.

Comment: Need not be Gmail; whatever mail system used by organization will suffice (e.g. MS 365)